# Prepend to String array

Tags: scala

I want to prepend an element to an array. I assumed I should use :+ but it seems this does not work:

```
scala> val nodes: Array[String] = Array("b", "c")
nodes: Array[String] = Array(b, c)

scala> val updatedNodes = "a" :+ nodes
updatedNodes: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Any] = Vector(a, Array(b, c))
```

How should I prepend "a" to give Array("a", "b", "c")

Comment: `val updatedNodes = "a" +: nodes` ?

Comment: so obvious! I'm still not comfortable with scala's 'operators". many thanks

Comment: well, remember simple rule, when operator ends with ':' it binds to the right when you use infix notation, so when your argument needs to be to the left of object then methods needs to end with colon.

Comment: Or another way of looking at it - the : points at the collection, the + at the element

Answer (score 5):

Refer to [Scala API for Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Array). Namely,

```
"a" +: xs   // prepend
xs  :+ "a"  // append
```

Also by wrapping the string in a singleton `Array`,

```
Array("a") ++ xs          // prepend
xs         ++ Array("a")  // append
```

Note also `++:` as equivalent to prepending with `++`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `+:` operator:

```
val updatedNodes = "a" +: nodes
```